# Exception classes for data entities in SpringBoot: a global exception class or an individual one for each entity?

Tags: database, spring-boot, exception, spring-data

Migrating a legacy database, I have created an entity class for every important table in the database, and then an additional repository class for everyone of them. Is it preferrable to create an exception class for each entity or a global one for all or them?

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of exceptions do you need to handle? Depending on your needs, the answer is different.

Spring provides you with a hierarchy of exceptions to create an abstraction layer over the concrete implementation of the data access API. You can rely on them for all the common exception scenarios when interacting with a databases.

> Exception hierarchy enabling sophisticated error handling independent
> of the data access approach in use.

The main exception thrown is `DataAccessException`, specialized by exceptions like `CannotCreateRecordException`, `DataIntegrityViolationException`, and `CannotAcquireLockException`. When data is expected, but non is returned, then a `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is thrown.

You can find all the exceptions in the hierarchy in the docs for the [org.springframework.dao](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/package-summary.html) package.

For other scenarios, for example to customize the exception management at the service/web layer, you might either create custom exceptions for each entity that need them or generic ones. It depends on your requirements. For example, you can create an `EntityNotFoundException` that you can throw whenever a search by id returns nothing. Or you can create an exception per entity in case you need special handling for each entity, for example `BookNotFoundException` and `AuthorNotFoundException`. Either way you'll have to explicitly throw and handle the custom exception.

Example of custom exception:

```
public class BookNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public BookNotFoundException(String id) {
        super("The book with id " + id + " was not found.");
    }
}
```

Example of throwing the custom exception, where `BookRepository` is a repository for the `Book` entity mapped to a `book` table in the database.

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public Book findBookById(String id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: The most basic exception I can think of, now. is not finding a record (you enter an identity card that doesn't exist in the database). It would be nice too warning about connection errors with the database ...

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details and examples.

Comment: Thank you. The Book example will save me hours!